# Flask app config take its default value instead of my config.py

Tags: python, flask, config

Here my flask app's config.py

```
import os

class DefaultConfig(object):

        PROJECT = 'SEARCH & FILTER '
        PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__$
        DEBUG = True
        TESTING = False
        SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'
        SERVER_NAME = 'https://s.herokuapp.com/'
        PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'https'
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
        SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
        NGROK_DOMAIN = 'https://s.herokuapp.com/'
        SHOPIFY_API_KEY = '*********************'
        SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET = '************************'
```

while I run my app, and tried to print app's configs detail

```
print current_app.config.get('SHOPIFY_API_KEY')
```

Its return NONE 
so, I try to print

```
print current_app.config
```

following details has printed

```
<Config {'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'ENV': 'production', 'DEBUG': False, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'TESTING': False, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(0, 43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SECRET_KEY': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(31), 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None}>
```

Why my given credentials haven't set to my app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you load your config into the application?

Comment: Using this code app.config.from_pyfile('helloshopify/config_app.py')

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load config using `from_pyfile` use these two files:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app_config.py')
print(app.config['FOO'])
```

app_config.py

```
FOO = 'bar'
```

If you want to use classes in your config, load the config using `from_object` instead:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app_config.DefaultConfig')
print(app.config['FOO'])
```

app_config.py

```
class DefaultConfig:
    FOO = 'bar'
```

Comment: I would like just to add to your answer my live example of app, you can check there how I load configuration.

[config file](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/master/config.py)
[perma link to loading configuration](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/5be5ebb17b40613a7a5ace698354f820151d07ac/aukcija.py#L21)

Everything else is explained by @Joost

Answer (score 0):

If your project's layout like this:

```
helloshopify/
    - __init__.py
    - config_app.py
```

And you load the `config_app.py` in `__init__.py`, then just need pass the absolute path:

```
app.config.from_pyfile('config_app.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import it and use from_object. Something like this:

```
from .config import DefaultConfig

#...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DefaultConfig)
```